# reuse nested variables declared in another repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

With Auzre pipeline, I would like to how to reuse the variables declared in another repository.

Just a background, if all the three files `organization_vars.yml`, `project_vars.yml`, and `cicd.yml` are in the same repo, without using the `resources` like shown in `project_vars.yml`, it works.

Now I need to put the file `organization_vars.yml` in another repository in order to share it to every projects in the same organization, I tried with `resources` as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#use-other-repositories , but it doesn't work.

In the pipeline, I got the error message `Unexpected value 'resources'` from the very beginning.

Hereunder a simplified example for the 3 files:

```yaml
# file organization_vars.yml in the calling repository

variables:
  orgName: xxx
```

```yaml
# file project_vars.yml in the caller repository

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: calling_repository
      type: git
      name: another_project/calling_repository

variables:
  - template: organization_vars.yml@caller_repository
  - name: callerVar
    value: $(orgName)_xxx
```

```yaml
# file cicd.yml in the caller repository, this file will be runned by the pipeline

trigger: xxx

variables:
  - template: project_vars.yml
  - name: otherVar
    value: xxx

pool:
  vmImage: xxx

steps:
  xxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by myself, just need to move the `resources` part from the file `project_vars.yml` to the file `cicd.yml`